# How might lions and orcs engage in warfare with one another?

Tags: warfare, fantasy-races, population, prehistoric-times, anthropology

There are two populations of beings in a world akin to prehistoric subsaharan Africa: lions and orcs. The orcs have essentially the same intelligence and physical capabilities as humans, but they are carnivorous and have no technology beyond basic stone tools like spears and very primitive axes. The lions are physically the same as real lions, but have intelligence and communication abilities equal to those of the orcs. Both species have spoken, but not written, language.

The orcs also have access to giant boar which they use as slaves. These boar can eat meat or fruit, and they have the speed and endurance of buffalo, but the strength and appetite of horses. They are used by orcs similarly to how humans would use horses: for labour and for war. The boar have been bred to have undying loyalty toward the orcs, and hostility toward the lions. Although generally unintelligent, the boar can learn language to a limited degree and use this to communicate, and they also have an incredibly high geographical and spacial intelligence.

Both species, the lions and the orcs, live in primitive tribes rather than nations, and these tribes are distributed across vast areas of land, such that communication between tribes can take anywhere from a few days, to months in the most extreme cases. However, the tribes of each species are united in their hatred of the other species, their love for their own species, and their desire to completely eradicate the other species. So basically I'm wondering, given all these factors, how would these species go about conducting warfare against one another in order to achieve the goal of complete extermination of the enemy? How might the conflict play out?

Comment: When you say the boar can learn language, do you mean as a horse can for commands, or that the boar talk to each other, like a monkey can be trained to?

Comment: They can understand commands, and can use learn and use language, but in a very limited way, such that they can only convey very basic messages, both to the orcs and to one another.

Comment: Do the Orcs ride the boars? I wouldn't think boars of any size would have a strong enough back, and you never stated that, but I was just curious.

Comment: Hello T. W. and welcome to worldbuilding! You definitely want to take the [tour] in order to find out what this site is about and what kind of questions are to be asked. You do realize that Homer composed [an entire epic poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliad) about *"conducting warfare"* and *"how the conflict played out"* during *just a few weeks* out of a war between two tribal coalitions? One can easily write a five-book trilogy about the war between the humane orcs with their loyal brutish boars and the talking lions. This is a perfect illustration of *too broad*.

Comment: @T.W. Can you add some more restrictions like the population size of each tribe? If the orcs are human strength or stronger? Do the Orcs ride Boars? Do the orcs use weapons?

Comment: My original intention was to have the orcs riding the boars, but I'm not sure how feasible that is, as theREALyumdub pointed out. The orcs are of human strength, and the extent of the weapons are the basic stone tools mentioned in the first paragraph. I had imagined the tribes having about 100-400 members each, but with scores of individual tribes for each species.

Comment: You won't get carnivorous tribes, very quickly they will use up the local resources and start eating each other. Warfare amongst themselves will be endemic and everything will fall to bits.

Comment: Which one has opposable thumbs? There's your answer

Answer (score 3):

The Orcs would win. They can build tools and weapons and shelters. Your lions are smart, but you said their bodies are the same as normal lions, so they don't have opposable thumbs. Also the Orcs have the boars which takes the burden of work and travel off them.

Giving your lions smarts does little to change them because they're bodies can still only do so much. Lions cant build. They'd still be pretty much lions, except they can talk. maybe they could negotiate they're way out of a pickle?

Seems like you haven't given the lions enough pro's to bring them up to the Orcs level. Maybe you could give them the advantage that there are way more of them than there are Orcs(?)

Otherwise the Orcs would basically kill off the Lions the same way that humans do now... use weapons and hunt them.